# How to manage newsletters?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have developed newsletter module for a single user and its works fine.

Now I need to expand the module for multiple users.

My question is that, how can I manage the newsletters when more than one user schedule newsletters for multiple subscribers at the same time?

I have thought it for 2 ways, First is execute 1st newsletter after it finished send 2nd. Second way is fetch random records for subscribers from database to send the newsletter so it will send it simultaneously.

Comment: Simple, don't do it on your own. Find a newsletter service provider which will take care of all the trouble you might get in if you try to do it all by yourself. From spam prevention to mail client support you will be better off using an established newsletter service.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I need only to know whether send newsletter one by one as inserted in database table suppose 250 per hour or fetch randomly 250 records per hour and send them the newsletter or do you have another way?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to store all tasks in the database and function that sends all mails and mark the tasks as done. This function I would execute using a cronjob.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

I would also recommend you to send the mails one by one (depending on how many you have to send) to avoid to become marked as spam.